# cholmod_factorize segmentation fault. How localize error?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sparse-matrix, suitesparse

I am sorry if this question is too ambigous or naive

I am implementing some mesh deformation algorithm based on optimization
Last step of optimization is solving big sparse matrix by sparse solver

I use cholmod for this task. But on some cases i receive segfault on cholmod_factorize

```
cholmod_sparse *A = composeASparseCholmodMatrix(........);//Creating my matrix. 
cholmod_factor *L = cholmod_analyze(A, commonCholmodPtr);
cholmod_factorize(A, L, commonCholmodPtr);//receive Segmentation fault on some cases
cholmod_free_sparse(&A, commonCholmodPtr);
//L are used for solving
```

So my question is in which cases cholmod_factorize can raise segfault? And how i can find origin of problem?

I cannot provide A matrix here because this matrix a real big (9000+ rows and cols, 45000 non zero items). Composition of A matrix is ok for many cases (8000+ rows/cols), algorithm works fine. I try to use error_handler from cholmod_commmon but i didn't receive anything

PS Sorry for my english

UPD
It seems that program fails then L->is_super is true

Comment: Can you give us a link to the paper you are trying to implement ? Are you sure your matrix is SPD ?

Comment: @Michael It no longer required. I switched to another version of cholmod and everything works. Also  CHOLMOD prints message if matrix is not SPD.

Comment: @Michael paper http://www.igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/arap_web.pdf